# Posting with snoopy using proxy takes too long

Tags: php, post, proxy, snoopy

Hi I have a php script which tries to do a post.
I use Snoopy class and also I use proxy.
I managed to post but when I use a proxy the posting is extremely slow.
I mean it can take till 30 minutes.
I don't want to block my script for 30 minutes waiting for a post.
Any idea how could I solve this?

The code looks like:

require('../includes/Snoopy.class.php');

$snoopy = new Snoopy();

$snoopy->proxy_host = "my.proxy.host";

$snoopy->proxy_port = "8080";

$p_data['color'] = 'Red';

$p_data['fruit'] = 'apple';

$snoopy->cookies['vegetable'] = 'carrot';

$snoopy->cookies['something'] = 'value';

$snoopy->submit('http://phpstarter.net/samples/118/data_dump.php', $p_data);

echo '

```
' . htmlspecialchars($snoopy->results) . '
```

';

Comment: Does this happen with other proxies? If not, then the proxy is simply slooooow, and there's probably not much you can do about that, short of using a different proxy.

Comment: I actually have a list of proxies which I use randomly.
is there a possibility to give a period of time and the if e.g in 2 minutes submit function does not return to try to change the proxy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var $read_timeout   =   0;  // timeout on read operations, in seconds 
// set to 0 to disallow timeouts
```

So, you could try to set $snoopy->read_timeout to any reasonable value.

Comment: I tried but it does work.
Still my script takes sometimes 20 seconds but sometime 20 minutes.